# No Many's Sky Quick Menu Ship Order

Tags: no-mans-sky

Does anyone know how the ships in the quick menu are ordered?

I know that in the quick menu you can summon whatever your active starship is, but in the section where you can go to ANY of your ships and summon them, what decides their order in that menu specifically? Is it by type? Is it by name? Is it by stats? Is it random??

I ask because I scrap a LOT of ships and the first ship in that quick menu is always the one summoned to the space station after scrapping. But the current ship in that position is NOT one I want to use to fly, so this gets really frustrating. The only option I have seems to be to just find one that goes in that first position automatically, but then I have to get rid of the ships I've spent weeks trying to find. Is there a way to know which ships will be in that first position before I spend more time finding ships?

Comment: Hi. Since you mentioned that your problem is knowing what ship will be made active after scrapping, I have tried to explain how that is determined. If that was not the info you needed, please tell me and I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is... somehow complicated.

You see. Currently the game assigns six slot to the six ships you can own (at least until a patch finally get us more slots).

Let's call those slots [slot 1] to [slot 6]. The ship you start with is obviously always assigned to [slot 1]. New ships you get go to the first available slot.

When you lose a ship, for example because you scrap it, the games tries to make the ship in [slot 1] active. If that slot is empty, it goes to [slot 2] and so on. **It is important to notice that ships aren't moved between slots at any time: once a ship occupies a slot it will stay in that slot until sold.**

So, let's make an example to make this more clear.

---

- You start with the Radiant Pillar. The slots now are

> [**Radiant**] [empty] [empty] [empty] [empty] [empty]

---

- You then get three new ships. Wandering Glider, Lucent Legacy and Voice of Gek.

> [Radiant] [Wandering] [Lucent] [**Voice**] [empty] [empty]

---

- You scrap Lucent. Radiant gets active (slot 1) and slot 3 stays empty.

> [**Radiant**] [Wandering] [empty] [Voice] [empty] [empty]

---

- Now you scrap Radiant. Since [slot 1] is now empty, games tries to activate the next one - [slot 2]. [Slot 1] stays empty.

> [empty] [**Wandering**] [empty] [Voice] [empty] [empty]

---

- You get one more ship, lets call it Viridiscent Hope. Like we said before it will go to the first empty slot - [slot 1].

> [Viridiscent] [**Wandering**] [empty] [Voice] [empty] [empty]

---

- you should now get what will happen if you scrap another ship. Since Viridiscent is now in [slot 1] it has priority over Wandering. So, if you scrap Voice it is Viridiscent that will get activated

> [**Viridiscent**] [Wandering] [empty] [empty] [empty] [empty]